# Storing a JSON Object value in a Integer c# . Windows forms app

Tags: c#, json

I have created a Windows Form Application Function to validate an Api. But the code is breaking ar Deserialize Line. I need to check for Status . If Status=1 is stored in StatusCode string. I can proceed ahead. Please assist.

**Function Code :**

```
private void Validate_CW_Account(string Company_Code , string Username , string Password)
        {
            try
            {
                string sURL = "";
                string baseURL = "https://www.compelapps.in/efacilito_UAT_Api/api/CocktailWorld/Validate_CW_Account_Migration?";

                sURL = baseURL+ "StrCompanyCode=" + Company_Code + "&StrUsername=" + Username + "&StrPassword=" + Password;


                var client = new RestClient(sURL);
                client.Timeout = -1;
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

                request.AddParameter("application/json", sURL, ParameterType.QueryString);
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

                string json_response = response.Content.ToString();
                
                CW_API_Response cw = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CW_API_Response>(json_response);
                
                string StatusCode = cw.Status;

                if (StatusCode == "1")
                {
                    lbl_AccountConn_Status.Text = "SUCCESSFUL";
                    lbl_AccountConn_Status.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.GreenYellow;
                    lbl_AccountConn_Status.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                }
                else
                {
                    lbl_AccountConn_Status.Text = "AUTHENTICATION FAILED";
                    lbl_AccountConn_Status.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    lbl_AccountConn_Status.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                }
                
            }


            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            
        }
```

**Class File Code :**

```
public class CW_API_Response
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Company_ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry it is unclear to /me what your question is, because if the statement "I can proceed ahead".   What is it that you need assistance with?

Comment: Hi Luuk , My Json response has 2 values . Company_ID and Status. I am unable to close the value of Status on the StatusCode Integer as the DeserializeObject is not working.

Comment: Once the Status value is Store in StatusCode, i can proceed ahead with the code it and use it check relevant conditions

Comment: [
    {
        "Company_ID": 11,
        "Status": 1
    }
]

Comment: Why do you have `string Status` in `CW_API_Response`? and not `int Status` ?

Comment: I tried the same. used int instead of string earlier. Facing the below error

Comment: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'eFacilito_CW_Migration_Utility.Forms.CW_API_Response' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Comment: hi @Luuk is my query clear now ? any idea on how i can resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the JSON returned by API is **[ { "Company_ID": 11, "Status": 1 } ]**  then you need to read JSON List. You are not reading list. You are assuming single value.

Try this:

```
 List<CW_API_Response> cw = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CW_API_Response>>(json_response);

 string StatusCode = cw[0].Status.ToString();
```